# C# Cannot read key valuenames

Tags: c#, registry

I'm trying to read all subkey on registry in C#
It's works well for native subkey, but when I create my own key, I cannot read it.

```
string all = "-start" + Environment.NewLine;
string registryKey2 = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\AnimateMinMax";
RegistryKey key2 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registryKey2, true);

foreach (string valueName in key2.GetValueNames())
{
    all += valueName + Environment.NewLine;
}
all += "-End" + Environment.NewLine;
MessageBox.Show(all);
```

[image]
[image]

"Test" Dword key is missing

Do you have some tips for that ?

Best Regards

Comment: Is you app 32 or 64 bit ? Also, your operating system? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Thanks @EylM I've uncheck "32Bits prefered" on build project and now it's OK :) Thanks again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong registry key section. Your application is compiled as 32-bit, but your operating system is 64-bit.
In this case Windows automatically redirects to `WOW6432Node` of the registry, where the key does not exists.

Solutions:

1) In project settings, change the target CPU to x64.

2) Use `RegistryView.Registry64` flag to open the 64-bit registry view.

```
var localMachine64 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
var key2 = localMachine64.OpenSubKey(registryKey2, true);
// rest of the code
```